# Sistema de itens estilo Skyrim

Tags: java, c#, orientação-a-objetos, design-pattern, engenharia-de-software

Estou desenvolvendo um RPG 2D em C# estilo Skyrim, e estou na parte de implementar os itens do jogo, porém com muitas dificuldades. Eu queria fazer uma mecânica semelhante a do Skyrim em que você tem uma gama de itens classificados de diversas formas como por exemplo `armaduras`, `armas`, `poções`, `anéis`, `amuletos`, etc. Alguns itens podem ser `encantados` e `desencantados`, mas *alguns itens são restritos a encantamentos específicos*. Eu criei um diagrama de classes para representar o sistema mas acho que não está muito flexível. Da maneira como se encontra, parece que se eu futuramente quiser criar mais tipos de itens, novas classes terão de ser criadas. Se houver 1000 itens no jogo e eu tiver que criar uma classe para cada um eu estou, como se diz, "lascado".

Outro problema que estou enfrentando é o da implementação dos encantamentos. Quem jogou Skyrim sabe muito bem como funciona. Suponha que você queira encantar um anel com um encantamento que aumenta o HP do jogador. Para tal é necessário usar um encantador e possuir o encantamento de HP. **Não vou usar o esquema das pedras de alma**. A efetividade do encantamento dependerá dos atributos atuais do jogador. Quanto mais habilidoso em encantamento, maior será a quantidade de HP adicionada pelo encantamento. Porém acabo caindo no mesmo caso dos itens; para cada encantamento uma classe?

Eis o diagrama: [image: Diagrama de classes]

Para contornar a criação excessiva de classes eu criei um exemplo só com a classe `Item` e as interfaces `Consumable` e `Equipable` mas não sei se foi uma boa escolha. Como eu identifico um item? Como diferenciar um item de outro? Enums talvez? Tive que passar um Player para o construtor de `Item` para poder modificar seus campos em `equip()`, `unequip()` e `consume()` e isso me soa muito como uma *gambiarra*

```
public class Player {

    int hp;

    public Player(int hp) {
        this.hp = hp;
    }

}
```

```
public abstract class Item implements Equipable, Consumable{
    Player possesor;
    String name = "";
    int price = 0;
    boolean questItem = false;
    boolean equiped = false;

    public Item(Player p) {
        possesor = p;
    }
}
```

```
public interface Equipable {
    void equip();
    void unequip();
}
```

```
public interface Consumable {
    void consume();
}
```

```
package br.com.interfaces;

import sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.NotImplementedException;

public class Tester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Item ringOfLife = new Item(new Player(0)) {

            @Override
            public void consume() {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }

            @Override
            public void unequip() {
                if (equiped) {
                    possesor.hp -= 10;
                    equiped = false;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void equip() {
                // Ok, eu sei, isso deveria ser um encantamento ,-,
                if (!equiped) {
                    possesor.hp += 10;
                    equiped = true;
                }
            }
        };

        assert(ringOfLife.possesor.hp == 0);
        assert(ringOfLife.equiped == false);
        ringOfLife.equip();
        assert(ringOfLife.possesor.hp == 10);
        assert(ringOfLife.equiped == true);
        ringOfLife.unequip();
        assert(ringOfLife.possesor.hp == 0);
        assert(ringOfLife.equiped == false);
    }
}
```

Acho que forneci toda informação necessária. O que acham? Aconselham algum `Design Pattern`?

Comment: Vc não precisa criar uma classe para cada item. Pelo seu diagrama "Armor", "Weapon" e "Potion" já contém as informações que você precisa, os valores de cada propriedade podem ser carregados via algum arquivo externo como um xml ou uma base de dados SQLite.

Answer (score 1):

Recomendo apenas que trabalhe com `Interfaces`, ao invés de apenas heranças. Neste artigo tem um exemplo legal, inclusive com personagens e armas, sobre [Injeção de Dependencia](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Dependency-Injection-By-Hand).

Eu não recomendo que usar especificamente o Ninject como seu DI. Eu recomendo o [SimpleInjector](https://simpleinjector.org/index.html), por ser igualmente de simples implementação, é mais leve e também o [mais rápido do mercado](http://www.palmmedia.de/Blog/2011/8/30/ioc-container-benchmark-performance-comparison).